# CSS - Timer Plugin won't show full

Tags: html, css

So I was working on this page here: http://dealsgoneape.com/test-timer/

At first look you'll only see the "DAYS" and "HOURS" but if you open the console or inspector tool on Chrome it will show up the Days, Minutes, Hours, Seconds.

I was wondering why. So I tried to play around with the HMTL by putting the following codes on my CSS and playing around with inspector tool:

```
soon[data-layout*=group] .soon-group-sub>.soon-group-inner{
   margin: 0 0.35em;
}


#frb_timer_643221721_timer .soon-label{
   width: 300px; 

}

span.soon-group-inner{
     border: 2px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

However, no matter how I tried to select the elements they just won't show up the whole timer without opening the console or inspector tool on Chrome.

Feel free to open inspector tool on Chrome or firefox to see this live.

Comment: You're missing the `.` from `soon`... but other than that, it's impossible to help without a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with a clear statement of what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya save comments for questions and clarification, it sounds like you have an answer.

Comment: try bringing inline display of span back
`span.soon-group.soon-group-sub {
    display: inline !important;
}`

Comment: At least tell us what is name of the timer plugin you are in need of help with?

Comment: I have found that, it's a width issue. so when you change the width of browser, for wider width, somewhere that I couldn't find, spans have made "display:none". so when you open inspector , because of it has made width smaller, every thing have gone ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css to force that `display:none` divs to show `inline block`

```
span.soon-group.soon-group-sub{ 
     display:inline-block !important;
}
```

output :

[image]

Comment: i think just bringing inline display of span back will do the thing, so you can do `display : inline !important;` also.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this page uses the FlipClock plugin: http://flipclockjs.com/faces/daily-counter

If you want to do this the "right" way, I suggest you read the plugin docs. Here is how to show all the number:

```
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(3600 * 24 * 3, {
   clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
   countdown: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the jQuery based **Soon, Animated Responsive Countdowns v1.9.0** here. So, while creating the timer in the builder you can set the Format to display Minutes and Seconds as well. Just like the one shown in the image below:
[image: Enable Seconds Values in Soon Countdown Builder]